# Hive - How to insert in a hive table an array of struct

Tags: hive, hiveql

So I learnt from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30446601/1773841) how to insert values into an array column:

```
INSERT INTO table 
SELECT ARRAY("line1", "line2", "line3") as myArray
FROM source1;
```

And from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39394499/1773841) how to insert values into an struct column:

```
INSERT INTO table 
SELECT NAMED_STRUCT('houseno','123','streetname','GoldStreet', 'town','London', 'postcode','W1a9JF') AS address 
FROM source2;
```

Now I was trying to insert in the same way values in an array of structs. Which has got the following schema:

```
additionalattribute:array<struct<attribute_value:string,key:string,value:string>
```

I tried to extrapolate like this:

```
  INSERT INTO table 
  ARRAY(NAMED_STRUCT('attribute_value','null','key','null','value','null')) as additionalattribute
  FROM source2;
```

But it is not working. Does anyone know how to approach this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the select statement after the table name. Demo

```
create table temp4
(
additionalattribute array<struct<attribute_value:string,key:string,value:string>>
);

INSERT INTO temp4 select 
ARRAY(NAMED_STRUCT('attribute_value','null','key','null','value','null')) as additionalattribute
FROM (select '1' ) t;
```

Comment: Thanks for poiting it out, but that is not the issue. I just didn't write the query completly here in stackoverflow and skipped accidentally the select

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre, I can run the query without problems. what is the issue? please add the error, Hive version and expected results if you can